# Node.js Ubuntu and Monit

Tags: node.js, monit

I'm working on getting a Node server up with `upstart` and `monit` instead of using a `cron` job to run a script to check on things.  I've built an admin dashboard for the server that uses the Node `os` module for things like `os.loadavg()` and `os.totalmem()`, etc...

The problem is, when `monit` is running, `os.loadavg()` always returns `[0, 0, 0]`.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Does monit create a lock or something that does not allow Node to read that property?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Monit Script**

```
check process flinch
    with pidfile "/var/run/flinch.pid"
    start program = "/sbin/start flinch"
    stop program = "/sbin/stop flinch"
    if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
    if memory usage > 0% then alert
```

Comment: Please include in your question the monit configuration you are using to run your server and the code of a server that minimally reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Louis Added `monit` script.  As I mentioned in my post, the code of a server that produces the problem is, `os.loadavg()`.

Comment: What happens if you stop monit and just start your software manually using `/sbin/start flinch`? Do you still get the same problem?

Comment: @Louis  No, problem only occurs while `monit` is checking that process, regardless if it is started from upstart, or manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give this question some closure, I removed `monit` from the system check and wrote a custom bash script that checks the process and it runs on during a `cron` job every minute.  Monit seems to put a lock on the system stats when in use.